# Spring boot making deployable WAR file

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, build, war

I am using Spring boot and Spring JPA Data to build a web application. 
The application works fine, but when I try to make WAR file to deploy it inside Tomcat 8 web server, I get these errors

Here is my Spring boot start class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
     application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootWebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and here is my POM file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-web</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>



<name>Spring Boot Web Application</name>
<description>Spring Boot Web Application</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <!--<start-class>guru.springframework.SpringBootWebApplication </start-class>-->

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <!--WebJars-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hot swapping, disable cache for template, enable live reload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>Mobl</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>


        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and IntelliJ Idea gives me these Errors :

```
Error:java: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file 
for groovy.lang.Closure not found
Error:java: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for 
groovy.lang.Closure not found
```

Comment: Did you ever find out the solution to this? I'm getting the same error. From looking at the stacktrace I think the problem is that the org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor class needs groovy.lang.closure for some reason. I'm new to Spring Boot and Maven, so I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot already contains a Tomcat container inside it, so your generated JAR file is executable.

Thankfully, Spring authors thought about some ppl still want to deploy Spring Boot apps into an individual container. Please follow [this link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/) for further info.

You need to configure the Maven/Gradle plugin to generate WAR instead of a JAR.

**Edit:** I just saw that you already have the configuration. If your application is working fine outside of IntelliJ then the issue might be that IntelliJ recognizes your application as a Spring Boot app and tries to run the JAR instead of deploying the WAR file as I think IntelliJ is not prepared for this case. You might have to write a custom configuration for it.